# ExcelPackage: Office Open XML

Tags: c#

I am new to this `Open Office XML` and I was wondering what file extension the XLPackage takes.

For example I assumed I just needed to input the file location of a CSV file I am using, but it does not work, do I have to convert the file to `.xlsx` or is there something other then the `XLPackage` that I should use?

The problem is that once it gets to the using a new OpenDialog is initiated and I cant find my file. I am probably just missing something obvious. File Contains Corrupt data, FileFormatException, I assume I need to convert the file before use?

I appreciate any feedback.

Some code:

```
    FileInfo existingFile = new FileInfo(eFilePath);
        using (ExcelPackage xlPackage = new ExcelPackage(existingFile)) // I think the                                       issue is here.
        {
            ExcelWorksheet exeedSheet = xlPackage.Workbook.Worksheets[1];
            //Total rows
            for (int row = 1; row > 0; )
```

Answer (score 5):

If you are working with a CSV the ExcelPackage is overkill for what you are doing.

CSV:

```
using (var Sr = new StreamReader("\\SomeCoolFile.CSV"))
{
    var text = Sr.ReadToEnd();
    Sr.Close();
    text = text.Replace("\n", string.Empty);
    var lines = text.Split('\r');
    var info = lines.Select(line => line.Split(',')).ToList();
    ......
}
```

ExcelPackage:

```
using (var fs = new FileStream("\\SomeCoolFile.xlsx", FileMode.Open))
{
    using (var package = new ExcelPackage(fs))
    {
        var workBook = package.Workbook;
        .....
     }
 }
```

Comment: The CSV solution you have shown above won't handle commas wrapped in quote marks correctly. Best using a library for CSV imports, IMO.